# How to wait for to Task.Run to complete

Tags: c#, .net, task, .net-4.7

I have a program that processes something like this

```
var t=Task.Run(()=>process());
while(!t.IsCompleted())
 Task.Delay(1000);
Console.WriteLine(t.Result);
```

Is there any other way to make the program wait till Task gets completed?

Comment: What's your purpose in using `Task.Run` in the first place? You're effectively asking for another thread to do some work for you because your thread's going to be busy - and then immediately turning around and saying there's no work for your thread to do until that other thread is finished. Why not call `process()` directly and use the thread you already have?

Comment: This is wrapped in a synchronous method. Task is the only way I felt.
Here process is an async  method.

Comment: You may do 
`var t=Task.Run(()=>process()); t.Wait(); ConsoleWriteLine(t.Result);`

Answer (score 6):

What you're doing here is *essentially* "sync over async". The **wrong** fix here would be to just... `t.Wait()` instead of your loop. However, really, you should try to make this code `async`, and use instead:

```cs
Console.WriteLine(await t);
```

Note that your `Main` method in C# can be `async static Task Main()` if needed.

However! There *really isn't much point* using `Task.Run` here - that's just taking up a pool thread, and blocking the current thread *waiting on it*. You aren't gaining anything from the `Task.Run`!

- if `process()` is synchronous: just use `Console.WriteLine(process())`
- if `process()` is asynchronous (returns a `Task<T>`/`ValueTask<T>`/etc): just use `Console.WriteLine(await process())`

Answer (score 2):

You have different options:
[`Asynchronous programming with async and await`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/async/)
[`Task.Wait`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.wait?view=netcore-3.1)
[`Task<TResult>.Result`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task-1.result?view=netcore-3.1)

Answer (score 0):

It happens automatically. You just need:

```
var t=Task.Run(()=>process());

Console.WriteLine(t.Result);
```

If `t.Result` is unavailable at first, the program will block at that point until the value has been calculated.

That said, if you just want to wait for the result, why run it as a task at all?

Comment: I think my last line explains that the whole approach is dubious.

Comment: Calling `Result` will block, rendering the use of `Task.Run` obsolete. The only reason for using `Task.Run` with synchronous code is to keep the UI thread free, so the resulting `Task` should be awaited.

Comment: As stated in my answer.

Comment: You just give the wrong solution, then say "but don't do this" and don't really explain why. This isn't an answer.